# Prepending text to a selected database column based on first 4 characters

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database table that has a path to an uploaded image. Sometimes this image points to an external server, but sometimes it is a relative path pointing to the same server.

When creating the SQL query I need to do this check:

1. If the first 4 characters of the path are `http` then just return that
2. Otherwise prepend hard-coded URL string to the path

I've been struggling to make the `IF check` check and `SUBSTRING` to work.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

prefix string

```
select IF(LEFT(column,4) = "http", column, CONCAT("string", column)) FROM table
```

append string

```
select IF(LEFT(column,4) = "http", column, CONCAT(column, "string")) FROM table
```

Comment: leo wants to *append* (not prefix) a hard-coded URL string to the path.

Comment: There we go, just a case of switching the concat col's around

Comment: Actually the first example worked perfectly, since I needed to prepend, which is exactly what the question says. Accepted!

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. It did say prepend in the title though.

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
CASE WHEN LEFT(url, 4) = 'http' THEN url ELSE CONCAT(<your hard-coded url>, url) END
```

Comment: @MarkBannister - Oops, updated with the CONCAT().  I've done it as a prepend (based on the title, and behaviour that makes sense to me).  Though an append may be correct as that's the wording in the question...

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
select concat(path, case substring(path,1,4) 
                    when 'http' then '' 
                    else hard_coded_url end) 
from 
...
```